# Target css:after via Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to target a css classname:after via jquery to alter a style dynamically?

I have a css arrow in a slider - i'd like to change color based on percentage complete - at the moment I have -

```
 $('.red-bar:after').css("background-color", "#1da9f5");
```

Which doesnt work!  any ideas?

Comment: It will not work as jQuery is not handling `:before` and `:after`. Psuedo-elements aren't part of the DOM so jQuery is unable to search for them.

Comment: i don't believe it's possible to target these with jquery

Comment: There are already loads of these questions of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `.next()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$('.red-bar').next().css("background-color", "#1da9f5");
```

More info:
`.next()` gets the next sibling of the selected item. If you want to add new content after the selected item, use `.after()`.

Example:

```
<div id="my_id"></div>
<div id="ignore_me></div>
```

Now, if you call: `$("#my_id").next().html("Hello");`, you'll get:

```
<div id="my_id"></div>
<div id="ignore_me>Hello</div>
```

But if you call `$("#my_id").after("Hello");`, you'll get:

```
<div id="my_id"></div>
Hello
<div id="ignore_me></div>
```